# How to download canvas from html using a python flask server?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have a html that has two canvas and a button on that respective page. When I press the button, I want to download the two canvas in an image. I've tried the following, but the downloaded image is empty (the canvas look good on browser):

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
      <script>
    function downloadImages() {
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById('bar_canvas');
        var canvas2 = document.getElementById('pie_canvas');
        var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
        var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

        // Create images from the canvases
        var image1 = new Image();
        image1.src = canvas1.toDataURL('image/png');

        var image2 = new Image();
        image2.src = canvas2.toDataURL('image/png');

        // Create a new canvas to hold both images
        var mergedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        mergedCanvas.width = canvas1.width + canvas2.width;
        mergedCanvas.height = canvas1.height;
        var context = mergedCanvas.getContext('2d');

        // Draw the two images onto the new canvas
        context.drawImage(image1, 0, 0);
        context.drawImage(image2, canvas1.width, 0);

        // Trigger the download
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'merged_image.png';
        link.href = mergedCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        link.click();
    }
</script>
   </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Data Visualization</h1>
    <button onclick="downloadImages()">Download Images</button>
    <div style="display: flex; margin: auto;">
    <div style="width: 600px; height: 600px; margin-top: 200px; margin-left: 200px; ">
    <canvas id="bar_canvas"></canvas>

    <script>
      var old_data = {{ old_data|tojson }};
      var data = [];
      var labels = [];
      var bar_chart = document.getElementById('bar_canvas').toDataURL();

      Object.keys(old_data).forEach(function(key) {
        labels.push(key);
        data.push(old_data[key]);
      });

      var ctx = document.getElementById('bar_canvas').getContext('2d');
      var c1 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: labels,
          datasets: [{
            label: "Data",
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: 
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
    </div>

  <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 100px;">
   <canvas id="pie_canvas"></canvas>

    <script>
      var old_data = {{ old_data|tojson }};
      var data = [];
      var labels = [];

      Object.keys(old_data).forEach(function(key) {
        labels.push(key);
        data.push(old_data[key]);
      });

      var ctx = document.getElementById('pie_canvas').getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
          labels: labels,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Data',
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: 
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Do you have any idea why the downloaded image is empty? Or is there an easier way to download the two charts?

Answer (score 0):

Result image is empty because Your merged canvas is not visible because not added to page. You need to add merged canvas to page, then download image, then remove canvas from page